# Does "extends" feature on Twig annihilate variables?

Tags: twig, symfony

The problem is when I send an email on fos user registration, giving the user entity to a template.

The following does not work :

```
{% extends 'MRPlatformBundle:Mail/MR/HTMLCSS:template.html.twig' %}

{% block mailTitle %}
    Hi {{user.username}} !
{% endblock %}

{% block mailContent %}
    {% include 'MRPlatformBundle:Mail/MR/Matter:welcome.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}
```

But, when I remove the "extends" part, it works !

The exact error is this : `Impossible to access an attribute ("username") on a null variable` (line 4)

As a response, I tried to use the embed tag, but the bug was persisting.

My question is : does the extends tag remove the given variables (from the Controller) ?

I hope I did not miss an obvious point... Thank you in advance

Comment: I can't add a "Hi !" or "Hello !", does stackoverflow remove it ? Er..

Comment: Have you tried {{ dump(user0 }} to make sure you the user variable is there and username is set on the array/object user?

Comment: Yes I dumped the user entity, and it is not a null variable. That's a mystery..

Comment: Ok I solved the problem by updating the vendor directory. No idea. But it is fine now...

Comment: and username is there? Try replacing you `{{user.username}}` with `{{ user is defined and user.username ? user.username : 'Bob' }}`  If you get bob there is something wrong with either the user entity or the getter for username.